# Error C4716 'Party::operator+': must return a value

Tags: c++

```
Party Party::operator + (const Party& party2)
{
    Party newParty;
    newParty.maxAttendees = maxAttendees + party2.maxAttendees;
    newParty.numAttendees = numAttendees + party2.numAttendees;

    for (int c = 0; c < getNumAttendees(); c++)
        newParty.attendees[c] = attendees[c];

    for (int c = numAttendees, d = 0; c < party2.numAttendees; c++, d++)
        newParty.attendees[c] = party2.attendees[d];

    if (date.compare(party2.date) == 0)
        newParty.date = date;

    if (location.compare(party2.location) == 0)
        newParty.location = location;

    if (organizer.compare(party2.organizer) == 0)
        newParty.organizer = organizer;


}
```

It is saying Party::operator+ must return a value. I tried returning `party2`, `newParty` and such but I get even more errors.

Comment: You need some sort of `return` statement. What exactly did you try and what errors did you get?

Comment: You should return `newParty`

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - if you want to `return` a `Party`, you need to have a working copy constructor.

Comment: ***but I get even more errors*** We can't help with errors and code we can't see.

Comment: Recommended reading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: It is strange that you only use the date, location or organizer when both match both for the attendees, you don't check for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is what it says on the tin; since you declared it to return a `Party`, you need to return a value at the end of the function:

```
Party Party::operator + (const Party& party2)
{
    // Some implementation...

    return newParty;
}
```

It wouldn't make sense not to return a value anyway since addition usually results in a new value of some kind.

---

Note: You might want to consider making your function `const` as well since your parameter is const:

```
Party Party::operator + (const Party& party2) const
{
    //...
}
```